# How to write a photoshop script to resize the image until it covers the whole canvas? (not just fit the height[or shortest length])

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, photoshop-scripting, image-editing, javascript

[How to Batch Resize in Photoshop](https://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-batch-resize-in-photoshop/)

This doesn't seem to work, so I think a script way might be what I need.

[Adobe Photoshop Scripting](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)

The resize method in its JavaScript reference guide doesn't seem to cover this (p.64).

(parts of the image can be hidden)

Comment: Could you add some examples of what you're trying to achieve and how the resize method in the javascript reference guide doesn't cover this?

Comment: It sounds like something which can be done without a script simply using an action. What is the difference between "covering the whole canvas" and "fit shortest length"?

Comment: no difference .

Answer (score 1):

Not *entirely* sure this is what you want....

If you want something to fill the canvas **and maintain proportions**, this script **isn't** for you.

---

I do this all the time. I struggled, like you, to find something that would *not* maintain proportions and merely fill the canvas, stretching or squishing as necessary.

I tried searching for where I may have originally found this script.. but honestly I have no clue. I may have even edited or corrected something else I found. It's been years since I first started using this script.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layer = doc.activeLayer;
layer.translate(new UnitValue(0-layer.bounds[0].as('px'),'px'), new UnitValue(0-layer.bounds[1].as('px'),'px'));
layer.resize((doc.width.value/(layer.bounds[2]-layer.bounds[0]))*100,(doc.height.value/(layer.bounds[3]-layer.bounds[1]))*100,AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
```

Will move a layer to top left corner of canvas, then resize to fill the canvas, ***not*** maintaining any proportion.

Note that *nothing* will be "hidden" using this script. When the script is called, *all* pixels on the highlighted layer in the Layer Panel will be forced to the canvas boundaries, regardless of what that does to the original proportions.

<sub>(If the original author presents themselves I'm happy to credit them.)</sub>

Comment: how to make it maintain proportion and resize the longer length to fit the canvas so that some parts can be hidden(fill the canvas)?

Comment: ermm ... you linked to viable answers to that question in the original question post.... but you need to start thinking of resizing the *short* edge , not the long edge if you want the canvas filled with cropping. Using the long edge will *always* leave empty spaces.

Comment: oh yeah. what do you mean viable answers?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layer = doc.activeLayer;

var b = layer.bounds;
var layer_width  = b[2] - b[0];
var layer_height = b[3] - b[1];


// put the layer in center

var layer_center_x = b[0] + layer_width/2;
var layer_center_y = b[1] + layer_height/2;

var doc_center_x = doc.width/2;
var doc_center_y = doc.height/2;

var shift_x = doc_center_x - layer_center_x;
var shift_y = doc_center_y - layer_center_y;

layer.translate(shift_x, shift_y);


// scale the layer

var scale_w = doc.width  / layer_width;
var scale_h = doc.height / layer_height;
var scale = Math.max(scale_w, scale_h)*100;

layer.resize(scale, scale, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
```

[image]